# What is the difference between wsdl mode and non-wsdl mode web service?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

i think most of the soap servers offer web services in both wsdl and non-wsdl mode (like Amazon does) for a client to make request. we know in wsdl mode client has to download the wsdl file to determine how to make a request for the service. but in non-wsdl mode, how the client learns to make a request for the service?

Answer (score 6):

In non-wsdl mode the client cannot learn how to utilize the remote soap server. This is up to you as developer. You will have to make sure that your client delivers what the server expects - especially parameter and response types have to have the correct types and formats.

In wsdl mode your client (i. e. Zend Soap Client) knowns which soap actions exist, how complex types etc. are defined and what responses are expected.

Personally I advice never to use non-wsdl mode, as there is imho no reason to do so.